# Boot VHDs using only the Windows 7 Bootloader

Tags: windows-7, boot, vhd

Currently it is possible to boot into a VHD by configuring the boot manager of Windows 7 once it has been installed. Is it possible to use only the boot loader from the install disk to boot into a VHD.

What I am trying to avoid is having two copies of Windows. One that I log into once and configure, and one that I use day-to-day. I would like to have only one copy of Windows, that being my VHD. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to just install the Windows 7 boot loader without the full OS being installed. There is also at this point no boot loaders that support VHD booting apart from the  Windows 7 boot loader. The question has also been addressed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/4203/is-it-possible-how-to-boot-an-xp-vhd-in-windows-7) and the one of the reasons for allowing this is explained [here](http://dotnet.org.za/ahmeds/archive/2009/06/11/virtual-not-supported-adventures.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Read the post here http://intellects.in/2009/10/23/boot-from-vhd-replacing-vista-or-windows-2008-bootloader-with-windows-7-bootloader

Sameer Dhoot